How to check what is the radius of convergence of a Taylor series with SymPy?
How to check the radius of convergence for a Taylor series?
Let's say you have a function $f(x) = 1 / (1 + a * x^2)$, then I can expand it in a Taylor series around zero, e.g.,
In [2]: series(1 / (1 + x**2), x, 0, 10)
Out[2]:
     2    4    6    8    ⎛ 10⎞
1 - x  + x  - x  + x  + O⎝x  ⎠

In my real use-case, the function is more complicated and depends on another parameter. However, everything is real.
Is there a function in SymPy to check what the radius of convergence is?
